# Como mudar valores de um enum dentro do próprio código?

Tags: java, enums

O que estou tentando fazer é que, quando eu chame um Enum, e instanciar, ele apareça com valor X, e quando eu estiver mexendo com ele no código, ele altere o valor para qualquer um que eu quiser.

Exemplo:

```
//Classe dos enums
public class Enumers{
    public enum Enumeration{
        VAR1, VAR2, VAR3;
    }
}
```

A classe que administra os enums:

```
//Classe em que estou tentando mudá-lo
public class ExtensionMouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener {
    public Enumers.Enumeration enumeration = Enumeraton.VAR1;
    public MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
    public Point mousePoint;
    public int z = 0;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        switch (enumeration) {
            case VAR1:
                //A imagem "IMAGEM1" já está setada e funcionando //corretamente
                break;
            case VAR2:
                menu.paint(g2); //A imagem "IMAGEM2" já está setada também e funcionando
                break;g
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        int mouse = arg0.getButton();
        mousePoint = arg0.getPoint();
        switch (enumeration) {
            case VAR1:
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (menu.mI.getRetBts(i).contains(mousePoint)) {
                        if (mouse == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                enumeration = Enumeration.VAR2;
                            } else if (i == 1) {
                                System.out.println("mudou Menu");
                            } else if (i == 2) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        switch (enumeration) {
            case VAR1:
                break;

            case VAR2:
                enumeration = Enumeration.VAR2;
                break;

            case VAR3:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

A classe do mouseListener:

```
//Classe do mouse
public class MouseAdaptador implements MouseListener, ActionListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    ExtensionMouse eM = new ExtensionMouse();

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        eM.mousePressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        eM.mouseMoved(arg0);
    }
}
```

A classe MainLoop

```
public class MainLoop extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Instances
    ExtensionMouse eM = new ExtensionMouse();
    //

    public MainLoop()
    {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdaptador());
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdaptador());
        setDoubleBuffered(true);    
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {   
        eM.paint(g);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        eM.update();
        eM.actionPerformed(arg0);
    }
}
```

O problema vem depois, quando eu ponho o método do `mouseClicked()` ou `mousePressed()`, que quando o mouse clicar na "IMAGEM1" o enum recebe outro valor, ou seja, o enumeration recebe o valor `enumeration = Enumeration.VAR2;`, só que, ao invés de mudar algo ou alterar a imagem, ele não acontece nada, e pior, ele muda o enum, e mesmo colocando `System.out.println` para checar, não dá nenhuma mensagem no console dizendo se alterou ou não...

Somente citei parte do código que estou com problemas, pois eventos do mouse, alterar valores e etc, não estou com quaisquer problemas.

Comment: mostre todo trecho de código porque nesse realmente vai ser difícil pegar o erro

Comment: o ideal seria você criar um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/3117), tá um pouco dificil de entender sua dúvida no momento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda vez que você altera alguma coisa no Swing (ou AWT) que demanda uma nova renderização, você precisa chamar o método [`repaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) para que o componente "se pinte" de novo.

Em outras palavras, o método `paint` não é chamado várias vezes sem necessidade (como num vídeo ou jogo, em que "a cada frame de animação" a tela é redesenhada), mas só quando se precisa e pronto. A imagem renderizada fica salva num *buffer*, que não é atualizado a menos que o sistema detecte que houve uma alteração que necessite de uma nova chamada do `paint`.

Como você está usando uma lógica própria, o sistema não sabe que "se a enum mudou precisa pintar de novo", então mudar o valor da variável no `mousePressed` não vai fazer nada. Experimente, no final do método, chamar o `repaint` no seu componente.

**Atualização:** Você tem dois problemas no seu código:

1. Há **`3`** instâncias de `ExtensionMouse` - uma que você criou explicitamente (`ExtensionMouse eM = new ExtensionMouse();`) e uma criada dentro de cada `MouseAdaptador` (que por sinal, você criou duas vezes). Como são três objetos, mudar o valor da enum em um deles não afetará os outros. E como o que muda é diferente do que desenha, fica parecendo que não mudou...

   Eu sugiro modificar seu código para que exista apenas uma única instância de `ExtensionMouse`. Faça com que seu `MouseAdaptador` receba um `eM` como parâmetro:

   ```
   public class MouseAdaptador implements MouseListener, ActionListener, MouseMotionListener
   {
       //ExtensionMouse eM = new ExtensionMouse();
       ExtensionMouse em;

       public MouseAdaptador(ExtensionMouse eM) {
           this.eM = eM;
       }

       ...
   ```

   E, na classe `MainLoop`, passe o objeto já criado para o construtor de `MouseAdaptador`:

   ```
   //Instances
   ExtensionMouse eM = new ExtensionMouse();
   //

   public MainLoop()
   {
       addMouseListener(new MouseAdaptador(eM));
       addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdaptador(eM));
       setDoubleBuffered(true);    
   }
   ```

   Isso vai resolver o primeiro problema: garantir que exista uma única instância de `ExtensionMouse` - e portanto, que quando você mudar o valor da enum numa parte do código (mouse) isso se reflita nas outras (desenho).
2. Como minha resposta original apontou, é necessário chamar `repaint` depois de uma alteração na enum. Sugiro que o `ExtensionMouse` guarde uma referência para `MainLoop` de modo que possa fazer essa chamada.

   Classe `ExtensionMouse`:

   ```
   public class ExtensionMouse implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener{
       public Enumers.Enumeration enumeration = Enumeraton.VAR1;
       public MainMenu menu = new MainMenu();
       public Point mousePoint;
       public int z = 0;
       private MainLoop main; // <--- Adicione essa variável

       public ExtensionMouse(MainLoop main) {
           this.main = main;
       }

       ...

       enumeration = Enumeration.VAR2;
       main.repaint(); // <--- adicionar essa linha após toda mudança na enum
   ```

   Classe `MainLoop`:

   ```
   //Instances
   ExtensionMouse eM;
   //

   public MainLoop()
   {
       eM = new ExtensionMouse(this);
       addMouseListener(new MouseAdaptador(eM));
       addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdaptador(eM));
       setDoubleBuffered(true);    
   }
   ```

   (eu movi a criação da instância pra dentro do construtor porque não estou certo se ela pode ou não acessar o `this` antes disso)

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, muito obrigado mesmo.
Infelizmente eu não estou conseguindo colocar esse método dentro da minha classe que administra esses enums, e infelizmente não poderei colocar o código completo. 
Já tentei colocar esse método (`repaint`) nessa classe, e nas outras qque estão administrando, tanto os enums com switch quanto a parte gráfica, e nada aconteceu. :/

Comment: @AndréElias Vamos por partes: 1) quantos objetos existem da classe `ExtensionMouse`? O objeto responsável pelo desenho é o mesmo objeto atualizado pelo seu `mousePressed`? 2) quem esse objeto desenha? Não é a si próprio (pois ele não é um `Component`), então deve ser outro(s). Mostre o código onde o `ExtensionMouse.paint` é chamado. 3) Ainda que não dê pra mostrar o código completo, mostre pelo menos a parte onde você muda o valor da enum (métodos `mousePressed` e/ou `mouseClicked`). Creio que a chave estará nesse método. Aliás, esses são métodos de um componente, ou estou enganado?

Comment: Ok. Eu dei uma modificada na pergunta, pra melhor entendimento de todos. Dê uma olhada...

Também, desculpe por alguns erros ou não saber algumas respostas, ainda sou "noob" em java, e estou aprendendo, e etc.

Comment: @AndréElias Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, agora ficou fácil ver onde estava o problema. Atualizei minha resposta, veja se isso resolve.

Comment: PUTZ Cara, muito obrigado mesmo, resolveu meu problema!!! Valeu mesmo, agradeço a você, principalmente, e aos outros que tentaram ajudar, mesmo que pouco, mas, ajudaram, :X

Obrigadão mesmo!